# ClusterIP under the hood

Tags: kubernetes

I'm interested how ClusterIP works under the hood.

When we create a service with type ClusterIP we get IP address, DNS name + Endpoint group based on selector in our service.

I don't  understand what ClusterIP represents itself.

Is it internal loadbalancer(software) like GCLB Or maybe all magic happens using iptables.

I'll appreciate it if someone explain or share the link with details.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the proxy mode used in the `kube-proxy` component. You can chose `iptables` or `ipvs` (proxy).

Some good reads:

- [Kubernetes Services Networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)
- [Kube Proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-proxy/)